# Как собрать библиотеку на С++ для использования ее в Python, в которой содержатся Qt объекты

Tags: python, c++, qt

Имеется код на C++, который использует в своей логике объекты библиотеки Qt, например:

```
#include <QString>
```

Я хочу класс из этой библиотеки (которая на C++) использовать на Python с помощью инструмента pybind11!

В файле CMakeLists.txt использую следующие команды:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.7)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")

project(srtmi, LANGUAGES CXX)


add_library(ti STATIC src/srtmi/ti.cpp)
set_target_properties(ti PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers")

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(srtmi src/srtmi/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(srtmi PRIVATE ti)
```

Вопрос заключается с в следующем - как мне добавить путь к библиотеке qt, чтобы компилятор его видел? Так, когда пытаюсь собрать библиотеку:

```
cd utils
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make ti
```

Выпадет следующая ошибка:

```
fatal error: 'QtCore/qiodevice.h' file not found
```

Если поменять строчку в CMakeLists на

```
"/usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework"
```

то ошибка будет другой

```
fatal error: 'QXmlStreamWriter' file not found
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
```

Я думаю, что компилятор не понимает откуда брать эти файлы, каким образом ему это указать в CMakeLists или может быть есть другие способы?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.27/manual/cmake-qt.7.html